# retrieve image from folder in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

imagedisplay.php(view)

```
  <html>
    <body>

    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

    <?php  print_r($upload_data); ?>   </br>
    <?php  $str=base_url()."images/".$upload_data['file_name'] ?>  </br>
    <?php $str=str_replace('http://','',$str) ?>

    <?php echo $str; ?>  



        <img src= '$str'/>  </br>
```

For ***echo $str;***  I got the string i need to display th image
***but when i pass it to img src.... i am not able to display it on the browswer***

Is there any syntactical error or am i missing anything ...pls help?

Comment: change <img src="<?php echo $str; ?>"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small syntax problem here.
Embed PHP echo command in the HTML code, like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo $str; ?>"/>  </br>
```

or embed PHP echo short tags:

```
<img src="<?=$str?>"/>  </br>
```

In other words: insert the PHP output at the positions, where you need it as HTML content.